# Unity C# application KeyNotFoundException

Tags: c#, mysql, database, exception, unity-game-engine

I am using unity to try and connect to a MySQL database.
The database runs fine, the code runs fine (in Visual studio 2010).
However when the following is ran inside Unity:

```
// Connect to database
private static void openSqlConnection() {
    string connectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=league;Uid=android;Pwd=secret;";
    connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
    try{
        connection.Open();
        Debug.Log("Connected to database.");
    }
    catch(MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex){
        Debug.Log(ex.Number);
        Debug.Log(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

This code will throw the following error:

```
KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object].get_Item (System.String key) (at /Applications/buildAgent/work/c514da0c8183631c/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/Dictionary.cs:150)
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.get_ExceptionInterceptors ()
```

This is a build for PC (ran in the editor) and to my knowledge this code runs in visual studio with the exact same MySQL DLL. Why does it throw this odd exception? I would really like an easy way to connect to my SQL Database from inside unity.

The dll i use is:

```
MySQL\Connector NET 6.7.4\Assemblies\v2.0\MySql.Data.dll
```

And the try catch block seems to be useless here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the dll provided with this question: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/216372/problem-with-mysql-connection.html
Somehow it magically fixes it. I have however no clue which DLL this guy used, or where to get the updated version of it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Unity uses Mono to run .NET code, not the standard .NET framework.

It expects a different connection string format, which is documented here:
http://mono-project.com/MySQL

Comment: Fair enough, i edited the connection string like so: `string connectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=league;User ID=android;Password=android;Pooling=false";` This however doesn't change a thing. Do i need to include a different version of the MySql dll perhaps?